# C# ASP.net Binding Images to GridView from list using HTTPHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler

I currently a have gridview that should be populated with multiple image preview using custom HTTPHandlers. I already have the list of items. The problem is, whenever I try to implement binding, all the images being bound are from the  **last entry** of the item list disregarding other items. I wonder why it is happening?

**MyHandler.ashx:**

```
List<string> items = new List<string>();
items = ItemManager.GetImages();


 public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        if (items.Count > 0)
        {         
            foreach (var a in items)
            {
                byte[] buff = client.DownloadData(a);
                context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
                context.Response.AddHeader("content-length", buff.Length.ToString());
                context.Response.BinaryWrite(buff);
            }              
        }      
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Gridview.aspx**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv1" style="text-align:center;" PageSize="6" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="10"
                         AllowPaging="true">
                            <Columns>

                                <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Select" ControlStyle-Width="100" ControlStyle-Height="30" Text="Update" HeaderText="Update"/>
                                <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Delete" ControlStyle-Height="30" Text="Delete" HeaderText="Delete"/>


                                <asp:BoundField DataField="a" HeaderText="ID" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="b" HeaderText="Title" />
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <img src="MyHandler.ashx" class="gridview-imgPreview" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="c" HeaderText="Caption" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="d" HeaderText="Description" />

                            </Columns>
```

Comment: Where do you tell the handler which image to display?  The handler code looks like it re-fetches the entire list of images and returns them all.  Which would result in either only the first or only the last being received by the client, depending on how the underlying system handles your attempt to return multiple files in a single response.

Comment: I believe it's in this block:
`foreach (var a in items)
            {
                byte[] buff = client.DownloadData(a);
                context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
                context.Response.AddHeader("content-length", buff.Length.ToString());
                context.Response.BinaryWrite(buff);
            } `

or am I missing something?

Comment: You're *definitely* missing something.  That block is called a loop.  It iterates over *all* of the records and repeats the same action on *all* of the records.  Nowhere is your `img` tag actually telling the request to the handler which image to display.  You should probably be including the record's ID on the `src` URL and then reading that ID in the handler to fetch just that one image.

Comment: I'm thinking that this `context.Response.BinaryWrite(buff);` would write the image file in every item present in the list. Or is there any other way to do this without incorporating IDs and such?

Comment: That writes one item. The fact that you're doing that *in a loop* writes all items. Do you understand what a loop is? It really seems like you're just randomly pointing at lines of code and *guessing* that "this line must be the problem." The problem is that the link to the handler isn't telling the handler which image to show, and that the handler is trying to show all of them. I don't fully remember the syntax in old web forms, but you need to pass the ID in the image URL. Then you can use that ID in the handler to find the right image.

Comment: I understand what a loop is, of course, though still new in httphandlers. As far as I can see these handlers have different behaviors that needs to be handled properly and incorporating the ID is pretty much the solution for this (as what I've read so far). I'll be posting the answer later, thanks for your help.